# Z-Order of Emacs Client Not Layered Top-Most

Tags: frames, emacsclient, linux

System & related settings:

- Fedora 35 (using Cinnamon Desktop)
- Emacs 27.2
- focus mode: "sloppy" with "raise-on-click" disabled

Contrary to all other applications, including the stand-alone Emacs editor itself, when opening a new instance of emacsclient, it is layered in the second position of the window z-order (that is, behind the currently focused application) and does not receive the input focus.

I also tried reverting the focus mode to the default of the window manager, but that made matters worse:  The window appears then on top, but the focus is still with the previously active application, which I can no longer see.  So, I need to use the mouse (or Alt-Tab) to focus it.

Further conditions I observed for this behavior to show was that the very first time emacsclient is opened (either starting the server with it or after the server was started), it works like any other application.  However, when opening it any subsequent times, the issue appears.

In order to allow "empty" Emacs instances to be opened as well as to start the server when it is not running, I use an alias with `--create-frame --alternate-editor=''` as arguments.

To mitigate this issue, I tried applying some solutions I found on the net as well as items I found in the manual (to be added to the init files), including:

- using `(raise-frame)`, or
- setting `default-frame-alist` with either `(auto-raise . t)` or `(z-group . above)`

However, the results do not do what I intend to achieve and are at times underwhelming:

- `(raise-frame)` does nothing (likely since it is run once at server start and then not again)
- `(auto-raise . t)`, like the previous one, does nothing I can observe
- `(z-group . above)`: While it surely brings emacsclient to the top every time a new instance is opened, in line with its description in the manual it actually pins it to the "always on top" group of windows, making switching between it and other applications cumbersome

Is there a solution to this dilemma or is this a bug worth reporting?

Comment: Not sure I can help, but I can spot one thing I can help with: the frame (as Emacs calls it; "window" in any other GUI app's terminology) which emacsclient opens does *not* belong to the emacsclient process, it belongs to Emacs. It is incorrect to think of it as "emacsclient [is brought] to the top" -- what is brought to the top (or not) is the new Emacs frame, created, owned and managed by Emacs in response to a message from emacsclient.

Comment: @PhilHudson, fair enough.  In the context of this question, however, I refer to the application window as drawn by the compositor instead of using specific Emacs terminology to keep it comparable to other applications.  "emacsclient" and "Emacs" are being used here to describe the mode of operation (client/server or stand-alone respectively), since even between them a difference of behavior can be observed.  I hope that clears up any discrepancy.

Comment: I can't really help either, but based on what happened when you changed the focus mode it sounds to me like the emacsclient window *is* always opened on top, but the problem is that it doesn't have WM focus.  My guess is that with sloppy focus, that simply causes the still-focused window to be brought back to the top so quickly that it looks like emacsclient was opened in second position.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/10249 or https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/9999 or https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/10364 are relevant.

Comment: @phils, the z-order of the application windows never changes due to focus change.  The related option "auto-raise" is on its default (off).  This is the intended way for me to work.  I already checked the related settings in Cinnamon and apart from the ones I mentioned, they are on their default values.  Again: It only happens with "emacsclient".  Using Emacs regularly, there is no problem.  So, likely no Cinnamon issue.  The only option so far that kinda helped was `(z-group . above)` with the side-effect of being "always on top", which I have to disable again as soon as I want to multitask.

Comment: Yep, not disputing that this is only happening for you with emacsclient; just suggesting that potentially it's not actually being opened in the second position like you thought (but ends up there for tangential reasons).